# Causal identification when some ITEs are 0

Tags: regression, logistic, causality, random-allocation

Say I have some data from an RCT related to a skills training program. The data are such that:

- Marginally randomized binary treatment `z`. Those with `z = 1` attended the program;
- Single binary outcome of interest `post_program_employment`.

Assume the randomization went great and we have unconditional ignorability.

After collecting the data, I realize that anyone for whom the binary covariate `pre_program_employment = 1` will necessarily also have `post_program_employment = 1` due to the way the data were collected. It is ambiguous whether these people actually got a new job after employment, or simply kept the job they had at baseline.

**My question is: can a logistic regression of the type shown below return an unbiased estimate of the effect of the treatment on the probability of getting a *new* job after graduation?** I am confused about whether conditioning on `pre_program_employment` in this way can account for the fact a person with `pre_program_employment = 1` must have an individual treatment effect of 0 in the data as collected, regardless of whether that person actually found a new job or not.

`m1 <- glm(post_program_employment ~ 1 + treatment + pre_program_employment, family = "binomial", data = dat_fake)`